# How to return a DataTable from .Net Web Service?

Tags: .net, web-services, json, datatable

I'v been able to return a HashTable from a Web Service that I setup for a .Net 2.0, but the service fails to retun a DataTable in JSON.  I keep getting the following error: 'A circular reference was detected while serializing an object'.  Any tips?

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true) ]
public DataTable getSavedAddresses()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    if (Session["ClientID"] != null)
    {
        int clientId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ClientID"]);
        dt = Address.GetClientShippingAddresses(clientId);
    }
    return dt;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circular reference is likely due to `DataTable` having a `Columns` property, and each `DataColumn` object has a `Table` property.

The information in [this blog post by Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/471835.aspx) may be of help to you, perhaps.

Comment: I think I'll just try using XML instead.

Comment: I think this answer is suggesting that a custom serializer is needed. That's what Rick Strahl does in the blog post, first with JSON.NET, then with the built-in JavaScriptSerializer library.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick re-visit to this old question...
I do it this way:

```cs
var header = datatable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(r => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(r.ColumnName, r.DataType.Name));
var data = datatable.Select().AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(c.ColumnName, r[c.Ordinal] is DBNull ? null : r[c.Ordinal] )
    ).ToDictionary(z=>z.Key,z=>z.Value)
);

return new DatatableRequestResponse
{
    data = data,
    header = header
};
```